Is it possible to validate a std::vformat format string only once?
I'm working with std::vformat in C++20 and need to format strings multiple times with the same format string. However, I noticed that std::vformat seems to validate and parse the format string each time it is called, even if the format string is the same.
Is there a way to avoid re-parsing and re-validating the format string on every call to std::vformat? Ideally, I'd like to validate the format string only once, and then reuse it for subsequent formatting calls without incurring the overhead of parsing it again.
Here’s a simplified example of what I’m doing:
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

int main() {
    std::string format_str = someRuntimeString + "{}";

    // First formatting
    std::string result1 = std::vformat(format_str, std::make_format_args(42));

    // Second formatting (same format string)
    std::string result2 = std::vformat(format_str, std::make_format_args(43));

    ...

    /*

    Imaginary code for what I might expect "single-validation" to look like

    auto validFormat = std::format_validate(format_str);

    std::string result1 = std::vformat(validFormat, std::make_format_args(value));
    std::string result2 = std::vformat(validFormat, std::make_format_args(value));

    */

    return 0;
}

In this code, std::vformat parses the format string each time it's called. I would like to avoid the repeated validation/compilation of the format string and use it more efficiently.
Is there a way to pre-validate the format string and reuse it without re-parsing it every time? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

std::vformat parses the format string each time it's called -- Processing redundant information in an efficient way is called memoization, and no standard function I know of has this built in.  Maybe store the redundant string and final calculation in a std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>, and then look in the map to see if the value has already been calculated?

vformat doesn't parse or format the data by itself, that is delegated to some formatter instance that can be user defined (for user defined types). There is no spec on how (if at all) this resulting information is to be stored.

std::format_string<int> format_str =" i={}"; now youcan just use std::format instead of vformat, so the validation part happens at compile-time only.

Except std::format_string can only be constructed from a constant, and the OP requires a runtime format string in the question.

This is possible in C++26 in a straightforward manner with std::runtime_format (or if you use fmt, before then) but I do not believe it is possible in C++20.

Neither runtime_format nor format_string prevent runtime re-parsing. The latter simply adds a validation pass at compile-time, while the former skips that pass, but any result of the compile-time parse is discarded. You also cannot parse a format string without knowing the types of the arguments, so std::format_validate(format_str) cannot possibly work.
The type-erased API, as specified, interleaves parsing and formatting at runtime (see the definition of basic_format_arg::handle, in particular the lambda in its constructor), so this isn't possible without some major surgery. I'm also somewhat doubtful that the parsing result could be stored in a (type-erased) form that would make this beneficial in typical uses. Parsing is typically not too expensive compared to formatting, and navigating the type-erased representation would have its own overhead.
fmt's format string compilation is the closest analog to what you want, but that requires the string to be a compile-time constant and the corresponding argument types to be known - and it comes with a binary size tradeoff.

using regex would be a workaround for validating the string just once and replace the rest. I used std::regex_replace.
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string already_valid_str = "The value is {}";
    std::string not_valid_str = "This does not contain format area.";
    std::regex regex("\\{\\}");

    std::cout << '\n' << std::regex_replace(already_valid_str, regex, "23") << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n' << std::regex_replace(not_valid_str, regex, "23") << '\n';
}

If necessary; std::regex_search could be utilized further to make sure regex matches before the replacement.

Using a regular expression adds a lot of overhead for a search that’s utterly trivial if you don’t use a regular expression.
